# how to check if two wrap error are equal in golang?

Tags: go, error-handling

I have a simple error wrap type in errdefs.go:

```golang
package errdefs

type errInvalidAttribute struct{ error }

func (e errInvalidAttribute) Unwrap() error {
    return e.error
}

func InvalidAttribute(err error) error {
    if err == nil || IsInvalidAttribute(err) {
        return err
    }
    return errInvalidAttribute{err}
}

func IsInvalidAttribute(err error) bool {
    return errors.As(err, &errInvalidAttribute{})
}
```

The following is a unit test of this file:

```golang
package errdefs_test

func TestWrapErrorEqual(t *testing.T) {
    err1 := errdefs.InvalidAttribute(fmt.Errorf("this is a wrap error"))
    err2 := errdefs.InvalidAttribute(fmt.Errorf("this is a wrap error"))
    if err1 != err2 {
        t.Errorf(" != now work")
    }

    if !errors.Is(err1, err2) {
        t.Errorf("errors.Is not work")
    }
}
```

then I run unit-test:

```sh
$ go test .
--- FAIL: TestInvali (0.00s)
    errdefs_test.go:62: != not work
    errdefs_test.go:66: errors.Is not work
FAIL
FAIL    errdefs 0.496s
FAIL
```

`!=` and `errors.Is` not work well,so how do I check if two wrap errors are equal in golang?

Comment: `fmt.Errorf()` returns an `error` value that's different for each call, on _purpose_. `err1` and `err2` has nothing in common except having the same error string. If you want to treat them as equal, you can't use `fmt.Errorf()` (or don't use `errors.Is()` to compare but I don't recommend going down this route).

Comment: is replace fmt.Errorf with errors.New ？

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? Comparing two error values is very atypical. Normally you would expect to test if a returned error value wraps a defined error, like `errors.Is(err1, io.EOF)` for example.

Answer (score 2):

The equality operator as well as `errors.Is` check the equality of the references of the error objects. So, two instantiated error objects will never be equal.

Most libraries instantiate error variables on startup and use the references for equality checks.

```golang
var (
  ErrInvalidArgument = errors.New("invalid argument")
)

func ErrInvalidArgument(err error) bool {
  return err == ErrInvalidArgument
}
```

Of course, you can also check the equality of the string returned by `error#Error`, if it is not dynamically assembled.

So, you test function would look like following.

```golang
func TestWrapErrorEqual(t *testing.T) {
    wrappedErr := fmt.Errorf("this is a wrap error")
    err1 := errdefs.InvalidAttribute(wrappedErr )
    err2 := errdefs.InvalidAttribute(wrappedErr )
    if err1.Unwrap() != err2.Unwrap() {
        t.Errorf(" != now work")
    }

    if !errors.Is(err1.Unwrap(), err2.Unwrap()) {
        t.Errorf("errors.Is not work")
    }
}
```

I hope I got your question right and this is somewhat helpful.